When we deploy our application into pod of EKS service on AWS cloud getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:Configuration.proxyBeanMethods()?
Getting below given exception when we deploy our MS (Application ) on EKS pod of AWS cloud but same code works on plain EC2 instance of AWS , Can anyone provide what needs to be checked in here ? All required maven dependencies and jars are identical in both scenario .
Exception :
org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class:
URL [jar:file:/opt/spark/jars/clouds-core-1.11.91_KAFKA_AWS21.jar!/com/clouds/core/main/RESTService.class]; 
nested exception is org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationConfigurationException: 
Attribute 'proxyBeanMethods' in annotation [org.springframework.boot.SpringBootConfiguration] 
is declared as an @AliasFor nonexistent attribute 'proxyBeanMethods' in annotation [org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration].
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration.proxyBeanMethods()

Application should run properly , if anything missing let us know .

Does this answer your question? Getting proxyBeanMethods() NosuchMethod Exception
